# Ajax post filter by taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I want to make a filter width more than one tanonomy width ajax and jquery,
The demo i want to code is: http://gycweb.org/resources/
I have tried to code with this demo: http://dinhkk.com/demo/ajaxfilter/

The problem is i can send in formation from two menu on right sidebar to the ajax data at the same time

can any one help me the solution ??

Comment: The link to the demo you posted is not working. Can you post here the code you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

I believe WordPress can handle multiple query parameter by default.

You can load `http://wordpresssite.com/?taxonomy-1=term-a&?taxonomy-2=term-b` to query all post that belongs to term a (in taxonomy 1) AND term b (in taxonomy 2).

Use JQuery `load()` function to load the intended query parameter, based on the selected item on the sidebar.

Hope this help.